# Как правильно отрисовывать объекты в java swing

Tags: java, swing, оптимизация, gui

У меня есть много объектов, которые хочу отрисовать на экран. Если дело обстоит в обычной отрисовке, то тут никаких проблем не возникает, все объекты отрисовываются моментально, глаз не успевает даже заметить что произошло, но когда мне требуется часто обновлять `view (JPanel)`, то тут возникает проблема:

некоторые объекты начинают пропадать на долю секунды и снова появляться, при чём неважно, стоит ли объект на месте или двигается.

Для обновления я использовал данную функцию:

```
public void slowMove(int x, int y) {
    int currentX = this.x;
    int currentY = this.y;
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        while (this.x != currentX + x) {
            this.x = 4 * x / Model.FIELD_CELL_SIZE + this.x;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(16);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            update();
        }
        while (this.y != currentY + y) {
            this.y = 4 * y / Model.FIELD_CELL_SIZE + this.y;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(16);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            update();
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Объекты я получаю из сета объектов и в цикле `for` отрисовываю их по одному.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(new Color(0x000000));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    GameObjects gameObjects = view.getGameObjects();
    if (gameObjects != null)
        for (GameObject gameObject : gameObjects.getAll()) {
            gameObject.draw(g);
        }
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Вот пример `draw` классов:

```
@Override
public void draw(Graphics graphics) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) graphics;
    g2.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй двойную буферизацию, сначала нарисуй все объекты на картинке(BufferedImage напр.), а потом уже ее.